# Post-build event syntax Visualstudio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to do some automation on my project build. I would like to ask user to input version number and then use it as an variable but i just can't get it work.

Any examples of syntax would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a batch file which is started after successfully postbuild which user asks for any input.
Also look [How to: Specify Build Events (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) and [Visual Studio Post-Build, Pre-Build Macros](http://www.dotnetperls.com/post-pre-build-macros)

Hope that helps

Comment: Is there a syntax example for it>?

Comment: On Build Events you can run your own application with DOS commands. For Example `MySerialNumberRequest.exe` which is writing the serial number in any textfile. Or syntax for copying stuff `copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)MyApplication-7\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\plugins\"`